# Unity Networking: Flipping sprites in Multiplayer doesn't flip host

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm working on a small multiplayer 2d platformer game. I've managed to get it to replicate animations, movement and flipping sprites across network, but I have a bug I can't get my head around. The code for flipping sprites works perfectly for the host - he can see other players switch sides when turning left or right, but everyone else cannot see the host flip. Also the third player cannot see the second player turn etc. Something is not right and it would be great if someone could take a look at my code.

Code in main **Player** script:

```
if (input.x > 0 && !facingRight)
     {
         FlipSprite();
         GetComponent<Player_SyncPosition>().FlipSprite();
     }
     else if (input.x < 0 && facingRight)
     {
         FlipSprite();
         GetComponent<Player_SyncPosition>().FlipSprite();
     }
```

Code in an additional **Player_SyncPosition** script on the player:

```
 [ClientCallback]
 public void FlipSprite()
 {  
     if (isLocalPlayer)
     {
         CmdFlip();
     }
 }
 [Command]
 void CmdFlip()
 {
     if (!isLocalPlayer)
     {
         print("Switching sides");
         facingRight = !facingRight;
         Vector3 SpriteScale = GetComponent<Transform>().localScale;
         SpriteScale.x *= -1;
         GetComponent<Transform>().localScale = SpriteScale;
     }
 }
```

**Edit:**

**Player**

```
Player_SyncPosition pSync;
void Awake()
{
    pSync = GetComponent<Player_SyncPosition>();
}

void Update () 
{
if ((input.x > 0 && !pSync.facingRight) || (input.x < 0 && pSync.facingRight))
    {
        pSync.FlipSprite();
    }
}
```

**Player_SyncPosition**

```
[SyncVar(hook = "FaceDirCallback")]
public bool facingRight = true;

[ClientCallback]
public void FlipSprite()
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    {
        CmdFlip();
    }
}
[Command]
void CmdFlip()
{
    print("Switching sides");
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 SpriteScale = transform.localScale;
    SpriteScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = SpriteScale;
}

void FaceDirCallback(bool newValue)
{
    print(facingRight);
    print(newValue);
    facingRight = newValue;
}
```

Comment: Do not use GetComponent. When you initialize the object (for example in Start() or Awake(), use getcomponent there, and keep it as a local variable. Getting the transform every time, is meaningless. Also, you can use this.transform .

Comment: Is `Player_SyncPosition` the second code block?

Comment: Done, but this is optimization, right? Still didn't fix my problem.

@user3071284 Yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced a whole variety of different problems (moving backwards etc.) and this is working:

**Player:**

```
void Awake()
     {
         syncPos = GetComponent<Player_SyncPosition>();
     }

void Update()
 {
  if ((input.x > 0 && !facingRight) || (input.x < 0 && facingRight))
         {
             facingRight = !facingRight;
             syncPos.CmdFlipSprite(facingRight);
         }
 }
```

**Player_SyncPosition:**

```
 [SyncVar(hook = "FacingCallback")]
     public bool netFacingRight = true;

 [Command]
     public void CmdFlipSprite(bool facing)
     {
         netFacingRight = facing;
         if (netFacingRight)
         {
             Vector3 SpriteScale = transform.localScale;
             SpriteScale.x = 1;
             transform.localScale = SpriteScale;
         }
         else
         {
             Vector3 SpriteScale = transform.localScale;
             SpriteScale.x = -1;
             transform.localScale = SpriteScale;
         }
     }

     void FacingCallback(bool facing)
     {
         netFacingRight = facing;
         if (netFacingRight)
         {
             Vector3 SpriteScale = transform.localScale;
             SpriteScale.x = 1;
             transform.localScale = SpriteScale;
         }
         else
         {
             Vector3 SpriteScale = transform.localScale;
             SpriteScale.x = -1;
             transform.localScale = SpriteScale;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The upper code work like a charm, but I think it can be more concise

```
[SyncVar(hook = "FacingCallback")]
public bool m_FacingRight = true;
[Command]
public void CmdFlipSprite(bool facing)
{
    m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;
}

void FacingCallback(bool _Old, bool _New)
{
    Vector3 SpriteScale = transform.localScale;
    SpriteScale.x = m_FacingRight ? 1 : -1;
    transform.localScale = SpriteScale;
}
```